# How to trim whitespace from a managed String in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I'm struggling to call the Trim() method on a managed string to remove any leading and trailing whitespace.

I've tried:

```
System::String^ filename = "   export.csv   ";

filename = System::String::Trim(filename);
filename = filename::Trim();
filename = filename.Trim();
```

This gives my errors of:

`error C2665: 'System::String::Trim' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types`

or

`error C2825: 'filename': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'

error C2039: 'Trim' : is not a member of ''global namespace''

error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Trim'

error C3861: 'Trim': identifier not found`

or

`error C2228: left of '.Trim' must have class/struct/union`

How are you supposed to trim a managed string in C++/CLI?  Why can't I use the [System::String::Trim()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) method?

Comment: how about `filename->Trim()` ?

Comment: @leppie: D'oh!  That works!  Post an answer and I'll accept it.  I've been fighting with C++ and C# all day, and I'm obviously losing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like you would do in C++, use pointer notation:

```
filename = filename->Trim();
```